# Mixing notes style and authordate style in biblatex-chicago (the example of letters)

Tags: biblatex, letters, chicago-style

I'm having a problem with `biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` style and citing `@letter`s. In line with the *Chicago Manual of Style*'s general guidelines, I don't list `@letter`s in the bibliography. Instead, I give them the `options = {skipbib=true}`. But then I cannot cite them as "De Sévigné 1750a", "De Sévigné 1750b" etc. either, as that is not enough of a reference.

I have read through the relevant questions that I could find on this forum, but as far as I could tell, none of them contained the answer to my question.

My question, then, is:

Can I cite `@letter`s according to the `notes` style, whereas all the rest is cited according to `authordate`?

I suspect this could be done by specifying a different formatting for the citations of items that have `options = {skipbib=true}`. Yet I don't know how to do that.

It's important, however, that the rest of the citation is in `authordate` format, so that e.g. the `@book` in which a `@letter` occurs would still appear according to `authordate`. An example would be:

> Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné, Paris, 29 January 1750, 100–110 in
>   De Sévigné 2015.

with `De Sévigné 2015` appearing in the bibliography as:

De Sévigné, Madame. 2015. *Letters*. Oxford: Oxford University Press.

Bibliographical info:

```
@book{DeSevigne2015,
bookauthor = {{De Sévigné}, Madame},
title = {Letters},
address = {Oxford},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
date = {2015}
}

@letter{DeSevigne1750,
options = {skipbib=true},
crossref = {DeSevigne2015},
bookauthor = {{De Sévigné}, Madame},
title = {Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné},
shorttitle = {to Monsieur de Sévigné},
origdate = {1750-01-29},
origlocation = {Paris},
pages = {100--110}
}
```

Can it be done? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please note that in the `@book` you should have an `author` and not a `bookauthor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't particularly pretty, but then modifying heavily customised styles  such as `biblatex-chicago` can get far from pretty very quickly.

The main idea is to execute the bibliography driver for the `@letter` entry with a few ad-hoc modifications

```
\usedriver
   {\clearname{author}%
    \renewbibmacro{cmsbibsortdate}{}%
    \renewbibmacro{bibprexref}{\addcomma\space}}
   {letter}
```

this is done in the `cite` macro as follows

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}%
  {\ifentrytype{letter}
    {\usedriver
       {\clearname{author}%
        \renewbibmacro{cmsbibsortdate}{}%
        \renewbibmacro{bibprexref}{\addcomma\space}}
       {letter}}
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}% Similar to notes+bib
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
            \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
            \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
            \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
            {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
              {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}%
              {}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:label}}
            {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
              {}%
              {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}% For names in []
                \ifentrytype{customc}%
                {\newcunit}%
                {\setunit{\addspace}}}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
              \iffieldundef{postnote}%
              {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
              {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand+title}}}
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
            \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
            \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
            \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
            \usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
            {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
              {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}%
              {}%
              \usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}
            {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}% Is this right?
              {}%
              {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}%
                \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
              \usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}%
              \iffieldundef{postnote}%
              {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
              {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}% ???
\makeatother
```

Note that you will need `mincrossrefs=1` for this to work absolutely smoothly.

Then we get

```
\documentclass[british]{article}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate,mincrossrefs=1]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{DeSevigne2015,
author = {{De Sévigné}, Madame},
title = {Letters},
address = {Oxford},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
date = {2015}
}

@letter{DeSevigne1750,
options = {skipbib=true,skiplab=true},
crossref = {DeSevigne2015},
title = {Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné},
shorttitle = {to Monsieur de Sévigné},
origdate = {1750-01-29},
origlocation = {Paris},
pages = {100--110}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}%
  {\ifentrytype{letter}
    {\usedriver
       {\clearname{author}%
        \renewbibmacro{cmsbibsortdate}{}%
        \renewbibmacro{bibprexref}{\addcomma\space}}
       {letter}}
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}% Similar to notes+bib
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
            \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
            \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
            \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
            {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
              {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}%
              {}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:label}}
            {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
              {}%
              {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}% For names in []
                \ifentrytype{customc}%
                {\newcunit}%
                {\setunit{\addspace}}}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
              \iffieldundef{postnote}%
              {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
              {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand+title}}}
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
            \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
            \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
            \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
            \usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
            {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
              {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}%
              {}%
              \usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}
            {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}% Is this right?
              {}%
              {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}%
                \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
              \usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}%
              \iffieldundef{postnote}%
              {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
              {\savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}% ???
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Beispieltext\footcite{DeSevigne1750}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Thank you, that looks wonderful! Is it possible to get the citation to use a comma and a lower-case "i" in "in"? Viz. Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné, Paris, 29 January 1750, in De Sévigné 2015a, 100–110.

Comment: @Mårten That should be possible, try the edited answer, please.

Comment: I have now also added the `skiplab=true` option so that the `@letter` is ignored when label extra-fields are created. We could also have used `dataonly=true`, which would be even more radical.

Comment: Das sieht perfekt aus. Vielen Dank!

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this. I'm currently experiencing the exact same problem but with the options `notes,short` instead of `authordate` for `biblatex-chicago`. With these options changed, it no longer works. Do you know how to make it work with `notes,short`? (That is, full letter citation in the footnote, followed by short citation for the `@book`, `@article`, or `@unpublished` that it is part of)? Thank you in advance. Please let me know if you prefer that I post a new question rather than ask you here in the comments.

Comment: @Mårten I think that is one for a new question (ideally with an MWE and an exact description of the expected output). Changes like this are tedious, but it should be possible.

Comment: You are right. I've asked a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398820/citing-letters-in-biblatex-chicago-with-the-options-notes-short . I understand that this kind of stuff is really tedious, and I understand if you don't have the time to work on it. Thank you anyway, hopefully someone might have a solution!