# Citing letters in biblatex-chicago with the options notes,short

Tags: biblatex, letters, biblatex-chicago

I'm having a problem with biblatex-chicago's `notes` style with the `short` option while citing `@letter`s. In line with the Chicago Manual of Style's general guidelines, I don't list `@letter`s in the bibliography. Instead, I give them the `options = {skipbib=true}`. But then I cannot cite them as "Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné" without further bibliographical information, as 1) the collection in which the letter is found is not shown and 2) if I cite two letters from this recipient to this addressee, written on a different date and/or at a different location, both will appear identical ("Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné") in the footnote.

This question is related to [another one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282135/mixing-notes-style-and-authordate-style-in-biblatex-chicago-the-example-of-lett) I posed some time ago. The difference is that now I'm not using `biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` style, but, as mentioned, the `notes` still with the option `short`.

My question, then, is:

Can I cite `@letter`s so that all the bibliographical information from the `@letter` itself is included in the footnote, but with only an abbreviated reference to the `@book`, `@article`, or `@unpublished` in which the `@letter` is found?

> 1. Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné, Paris, 29 January 1750,
>      100–110 in De Sévigné, *Letters*.
> 2. Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné, Paris, 1 February 1751,
>      111–113 in De Sévigné, *Letters*.

with "De Sévigné, *Letters*" appearing in the bibliography as:

> De Sévigné, Madame. *Letters*. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2015.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,short]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{DeSevigne2015,
author = {{De Sévigné}, Madame},
title = {Letters},
address = {Oxford},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
date = {2015}
}

@letter{DeSevigne1750,
options = {skipbib=true,skiplab=true},
crossref = {DeSevigne2015},
title = {Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné},
shorttitle = {to Monsieur de Sévigné},
origdate = {1750-01-29},
origlocation = {Paris},
pages = {100--110}
}

@letter{DeSevigne1751,
options = {skipbib=true,skiplab=true},
crossref = {DeSevigne2015},
title = {Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné},
shorttitle = {to Monsieur de Sévigné},
origdate = {1751-02-01},
origlocation = {Paris},
pages = {111--113}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

A first letter to her husband.\footcite{DeSevigne1750} Then a second letter to her husband.\footcite{DeSevigne1751}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The necessary changes are similar to the ones in [Mixing notes style and authordate style in biblatex-chicago (the example of letters)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282135/35864), but this time we need to modify `cite:short`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,short]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{DeSevigne2015,
author = {{De Sévigné}, Madame},
title = {Letters},
address = {Oxford},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
date = {2015}
}

@letter{DeSevigne1750,
options = {skipbib=true,skiplab=true},
crossref = {DeSevigne2015},
title = {Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné},
shorttitle = {to Monsieur de Sévigné},
origdate = {1750-01-29},
origlocation = {Paris},
pages = {100--110}
}

@letter{DeSevigne1751,
options = {skipbib=true,skiplab=true},
crossref = {DeSevigne2015},
title = {Madame de Sévigné to Monsieur de Sévigné},
shorttitle = {to Monsieur de Sévigné},
origdate = {1751-02-01},
origlocation = {Paris},
pages = {111--113}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \ifentrytype{letter}
    {\usedriver
       {\clearname{author}%
        \clearname{editor}%
        \renewbibmacro{xrefprenote}{\space}}
       {letter}}
    {\usebibmacro{allshort+firstcite+xref}%
     \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
     \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
     \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
     \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
       {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}\AND\NOT%
        \ifentrytype{periodical}}% Simplify .bib creation
       {\ifuseauthor%
         {\ifboolexpr{%
             not test {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}}%
             and
             ((
             test {\ifcitation}%
             and
             togl {cms@citejtabb}%
             )
             or
             (
             test {\ifbibliography}%
             and
             togl {cms@bibjtabb}%
             ))
           }%
           {\printfield[shortjournal]{shortjournal}\newcunit}%
           {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\newcunit}}%
         {}}%
       {\ifentrytype{manual}%
         {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
         {}}}%
     {\ifboolexpr{%
         test {\ifciteidem}%
         and
         not test {\ifbibliography}%
         and
         not test {\iffirstonpage}%
         and
         not togl {cms@noidem}%
         and
         not togl {cms@headlessnote}%
       }%
       {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
         \classicpunct}%
       {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
         {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
           \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
         {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
           {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
             \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
           {\printnames{labelname}%\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%
             \isdot\classicpunct}}}}%
     \ifboolexpr{%
       togl {cms@allshort}%
       or
       test {\ifbibliography}%
     }%
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
     {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A first letter to her husband.\footcite{DeSevigne1750} Then a second letter to her husband.\footcite{DeSevigne1751}

A first letter to her husband.\footcite{DeSevigne1750} Then a second letter to her husband.\footcite{DeSevigne1751}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks great, thank you so much! I noticed, however, that if the `@book` that a `@letter` is in has an `editor` in addition to an `author`, the `editor` will be inherited by the `@letter` (through `crossref`) and placed at the head of the citation, which is not desirable. The `editor` should still refer to the `@book` only. You should see this if you add an `editor` to `DeSevigne2015` in the MWE. Do you know if this can be prevented? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @Mårten I added an easy solution. It is not particularly elegant, but if a `@letter` never has an editor it should be fine.

Comment: Fantastic! That shouldn't be a problem, I haven't encountered a situation in which I wanted to give a letter (rather than the collection in which it is included) an editor, so this will work. Thanks again!